# Al insertar una webapp hecha con google apps script en google sites dejan de funcionar los links

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sites

Inserté la webapp que hice con google apps script en google sites pero dejaron de funcionar los links que tenía, ahora cuando doy click al link no me lleva a la URL que necesito.
Anteriormente (antes de insertarlo en google sites) funcionaba muy bien pero ahora aparece un mensaje diciendo ''Otro usuario ha creado esta aplicación, no Google.''

```javascript
//Código G.S.
function doGet (e) {
    if (e.parameter.v == 'index'){
      return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();
    } else {
      return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Pag1').evaluate();
    }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>   
   <a href="<?=ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();?>?v=pag1"><h2>Página 1</h2></a><br>
  </body>
</html>
```

Pag1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="<?=ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();?>?v=index"><h2>Index</h2></a><br>
  </body>
</html>
```

En Google Sites no sirven los vínculos, no me lleva de una página a otra.
Cuando se carga la página en google sites y cuando doy click al link me aparece este error en la consola:

> Unsafe attempt to initiate navigation for frame with origin '`https://sites.google.com`' from frame with URL '`https://n-ktgalt6nwnovikfknkc73qq5cs6kkcwqyjs524a-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel`'. The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed, but the flag of 'allow-top-navigation' or 'allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation' is not set.

Comment: Por favor agrega un [mcve].

Comment: Los mensajes de error deben agregarse como texto, no como imagen. Nuevamente, por favor agrega un [mcve], esto quiere decir que agregues el código del .gs y si estas usando .html también este pero no todo el código, sólo lo mínimo necesario para reproducir el error. P.S. Parte del problema podría ser que te falta usar `setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)`.

Comment: @Rubén Ya hice los cambios necesarios, espero que la pregunta haya quedado publicada correctamente. Agradecería mucho la ayuda porque no estoy pudiendo solucionar este problema

Comment: @ZHC He borrado mi respuesta porque no actualmente no está funcionando la solución sugerida.  Me temo que Google Sites está bloqueando este tipo de enlaces. Una opción es que en lugar de abrir una página actualices el contenido de la misma tipo SPA (single page application / aplicación de una sóla página). Esto se hace usando JavaScript del lado cliente para actualizar el DOM.